# sass doesn't create css files

Tags: sass

In my terminal i run the command "sass --watch sass:styles" to create the css files as i save a .scss i worked on.
Sass always detects that changes are made, i get lines like

```
>>> Change detected to: 
/sass/_styles.scss
```

Normally it then gives a line like

```
overwrite styles/screen.css
```

But doesn't always do that, i stops at the change detected. I have to save the file several (10-15) times before he gets to the overwrite part.

I recently changed from a Ubuntu to a CentOS server and since then the problem got a lot persistent. On the Ubuntu this came up every once and a while but on the new server it happens with every file, every time i save.

I installed ruby 1.9.2 on the CentOS.
And i login on the server with sftp to edit the files.

Comment: Just to be absolutely completely clear and forgive me for clarifying. Are you running `sass --watch` on your local machine or the server? If you're editing the files via sftp and watching for changes locally...

Comment: I'm having the same problem...locally

Comment: Ran it as root, now it works.  Even tried chmod'ing and chown'ing the directories of stylesheets recursively.  That didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to remove the "_" from the _styles.scss. SASS will not create a corresponding css file if a filename start with _. This is usefull for partials.

More info:
http://sass-lang.com/guide#4